# Proof of Hales-Jewett Theorem

Tags: co.combinatorics, ramsey-theory

I was studying the paper '[Set-polynomials and polynomial extension of the Hales-Jewett Theorem](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9907201)' by Bergelson & Leibman, and I'm having problem with the proof of 'Proposition L', which is (for the van der Waerden theorem):

**Proposition L.(vdW)** Let $(X,\rho)$ be a compact metric space. $q\in \mathbb{N}$. Let $T$ be a continuous self-mapping of $X$. Let $A$ be a set consisting of $q$ pairwise distinct natural numbers $A=\{p_i\in \mathbb{N}: i=1,...q\}$; assume without loss of generality that $p_1<...<p_q$.
$\quad$ Then for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N\in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$, such that for any $x\in X$ there exists $n\leq N, n\neq 0$, and $a\leq p_q(N-n)$ such that for any $p\in A$,$$\rho (T^{a+pn}x,T^ax)<\epsilon.$$

$\quad$ The proof of the above proposition proceeds by induction on $q$, the cardinality of $A$. But they didn't prove the proposition when $q=|A|=1$. And I got stuck there, and I don't have any idea how to proceed.

$\quad$ So, my problem is to prove the stated proposition when $q=|A|=1$. Can anyone help me on that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: By compactness, the space $X$ can be covered by a finite number, say $M$, open balls of radius $\epsilon/2$. So any sequence in $X$ will have, among any $M+1$ of its terms, at least two that are in the same one of these balls and therefore within $\epsilon$ of each other.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Didn't have any idea that the answer could be so simple. Thank you very much.